# Function call in postgresql returns no resultset

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.4

I have a postgresql function like

```
create or replace function getalltypes(name character varying(100))
returns  setof docs as $BODY$ 

begin
perform c.contenttypename from conttype c;

end;
$BODY$  LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

docs is a type I have created

```
create type docs as (contenttypename character varying(100))
```

on

```
select getalltypes('')
```

No result is getting displayed. Can anyone please help?

Comment: you probably want to change `perform c.contenttypename from conttype c;` to `return query c.contenttypename from conttype c;` ?..

Comment: @VaoTsun  -   'return query c.contenttypename from conttype c;' is showing an error at 'c'. I changed to 'return query select c.contenttypename from conttype c;' Then it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any return statement. This is why you see no result.
`PERFORM` [is used to evaluate the query and DISCARD the result](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-statements.html)
This is why you should change `perform c.contenttypename from conttype c;` to smth like `return query select c.contenttypename from conttype c;`.